# How to publish an app which only works if there is a direct connection to our machine via wifi (Google Play Store and App Store

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect

I have developed an app that communicates with our machine via Wi-Fi. You can think of it like an app that is used at car gas stations, such as Shell, Fillibri or the ryd app. This means that the app can only be used when the customer is in front of our machine. If the customer is not directly in front of our machine, the app cannot be used and the customer only sees a message.

My question:
How can I implement an access for the app review in the app stores, since the app only works when the app is connected to or machine via Wi-Fi.

I didn't find something in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same problem:

**Apple**: Rejected the app, then we provided them with a video link that show every feature in the app and we explained that it is can not be used without the related hardware. we had to film a user using the app from another phone (not screen recording). make sure the video is clear and not shaky, and provide a full text step-by-step explanation of the cycle.

**Google Play:** Did not reject the app, but we provided the link to the same video anyway in the "Needed credentials" section

Comment: Hello Jabbar, thanks for your reply.

Did Apple ask for such a video or was it your idea?

I think we will make a video like this and make it available to Apple and Google Play.

You helped me a lot thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, Apple asked us to provide a video that shows all app features.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar product. The solution is not exactly simple. We shipped the machine to Apple / Google so the reviewers can use it to test / validate your releases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

Due to the size of our system (2.5m x 2.5m x2m) shipping is not easy and would be expensive.

But for smaller systems this is a possible solution.